# Is it possible to acces the old file upload value?

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5.3

When editing my form, how do I get the old file upload value?

My code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <img src="{{isset($step) && $step->icon ? icon_url($step->icon) : 'http://placehold.it/300?text=Stap icoon'}}" height="260" width="300"}}>
</div>                    

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="icon">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use database for this  you need to save the file name 
in database and file in a particular folder